# How to print a table with C on MacOS?

Tags: c, macos

I trying to write a C program on macos which is printing a table. I thought about using codepages but I was recommended to use Unicode.

But how can I print a table with Unicode on mac? Because I can´t find any symbols for tables in Unicode. When I try to print the ones I find It always prints the Unicode defenition and not the table symbol.
For example:

```
printf("0x2605\n");
return 0;
```

gives me the output:

```
0x2605
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The code page is an ugly Windows hack to allow ancient computers to deal with non US-English characters. Macs use Unicode everywhere and can support all characters without such ugliness. TLDR; you don't need it. If you want the registered trademark symbol, try `Option+R`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. But how can I make a table with Unicode? Codepage 850 has some symbols to make a table, I can’t find those in Unicode.

Comment: Please update your question so it actually represents what you want to do - you are much more likely to get a better answer that way - just click `edit` underneath it. Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion: stick with ASCII chars: `+-------+-----+`, `| Foobar | 42.0 |`, ...

Comment: Please review your question. Your last edit made things worse, but the question seemed inconsistent and unclear also in the previous version.

Comment: `I can´t find any symbols for tables in Unicode.` Really? Like my google https://www.google.com/search?q=draw+table+with+unicode resolted in [this amazing characters list](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2500-257F). There's also a [wiki page just for box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. But how can I print those with `printf(" ")`? Sorry for those questions but I´m new to C and don't know much about it.

Comment: Perhaps with C11:  `printf("\u2605\n");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print non ASCII characters on MacOS, you should select a UTF-8 encoded locale such as `en_US.UTF-8` and use `%lc` to convert unicode code point values to UTF-8 byte sequences.

Here is a short example:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");

    for (int c = 0x2600; c <= 0x26FF; c++) {
        printf("%lc%c", c, " \n"[c % 32 == 31]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
☀ ☁ ☂ ☃ ☄ ★ ☆ ☇ ☈ ☉ ☊ ☋ ☌ ☍ ☎ ☏ ☐ ☑ ☒ ☓ ☔ ☕ ☖ ☗ ☘ ☙ ☚ ☛ ☜ ☝ ☞ ☟
☠ ☡ ☢ ☣ ☤ ☥ ☦ ☧ ☨ ☩ ☪ ☫ ☬ ☭ ☮ ☯ ☰ ☱ ☲ ☳ ☴ ☵ ☶ ☷ ☸ ☹ ☺ ☻ ☼ ☽ ☾ ☿
♀ ♁ ♂ ♃ ♄ ♅ ♆ ♇ ♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓ ♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙ ♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟
♠ ♡ ♢ ♣ ♤ ♥ ♦ ♧ ♨ ♩ ♪ ♫ ♬ ♭ ♮ ♯ ♰ ♱ ♲ ♳ ♴ ♵ ♶ ♷ ♸ ♹ ♺ ♻ ♼ ♽ ♾ ♿
⚀ ⚁ ⚂ ⚃ ⚄ ⚅ ⚆ ⚇ ⚈ ⚉ ⚊ ⚋ ⚌ ⚍ ⚎ ⚏ ⚐ ⚑ ⚒ ⚓ ⚔ ⚕ ⚖ ⚗ ⚘ ⚙ ⚚ ⚛ ⚜ ⚝ ⚞ ⚟
⚠ ⚡ ⚢ ⚣ ⚤ ⚥ ⚦ ⚧ ⚨ ⚩ ⚪ ⚫ ⚬ ⚭ ⚮ ⚯ ⚰ ⚱ ⚲ ⚳ ⚴ ⚵ ⚶ ⚷ ⚸ ⚹ ⚺ ⚻ ⚼ ⚽ ⚾ ⚿
⛀ ⛁ ⛂ ⛃ ⛄ ⛅ ⛆ ⛇ ⛈ ⛉ ⛊ ⛋ ⛌ ⛍ ⛎ ⛏ ⛐ ⛑ ⛒ ⛓ ⛔ ⛕ ⛖ ⛗ ⛘ ⛙ ⛚ ⛛ ⛜ ⛝ ⛞ ⛟
⛠ ⛡ ⛢ ⛣ ⛤ ⛥ ⛦ ⛧ ⛨ ⛩ ⛪ ⛫ ⛬ ⛭ ⛮ ⛯ ⛰ ⛱ ⛲ ⛳ ⛴ ⛵ ⛶ ⛷ ⛸ ⛹ ⛺ ⛻ ⛼ ⛽ ⛾ ⛿
```

Depending on the terminal application and the elected font, some Unicode glyphs might look different:

- Here is a snapshot using the standard Terminal application:

[image]

- Here is a snapshot using the advanced iTerm2 application:

[image]